# Akka Streams: Throttling a File Source

Tags: akka, akka-stream

Ive got a file containing several thousand lines like this.

```
Mr|David|Smith|david.smith@gmail.com
Mrs|Teri|Smith|teri.smith@gmail.com
...
```

I want to read the file emitting each line downstream but in a throttled manner ie. 1 per/sec.

I cannot quite figure out how to get the throttling working in the flow.

`flow1` (below) outputs the first line after 1 sec and then terminates.
`flow2` (below) waits 1 sec then outputs the whole file.

```
val source: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.fromPath(file)

val flow1 = Flow[ByteString].
              via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator),10000)).
              throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping).
              map(bs => bs.utf8String)

val flow2 = Flow[ByteString].
              throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping).
              via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), 10000)).
              map(bs => bs.utf8String)

val sink = Sink.foreach(println)
val res = source.via(flow2).to(sink).run().onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

I couldn't glean any solution from studying the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Framing$.html).

Would greatly appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `runWith`, instead of `to`, with `flow1`:

```scala
val source: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.fromPath(file)

val flow1 = 
  Flow[ByteString]
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), 10000))
    .throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
    .map(bs => bs.utf8String)

val sink = Sink.foreach(println)

source.via(flow1).runWith(sink).onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

`to` returns the materialized value of the `Source` (i.e., the `source.via(flow1)`), so you're terminating the actor system when the "left-hand side" of the stream is completed. What you want to do is to shut down the system when the materialized value of the `Sink` is completed. Using `runWith` returns the materialized value of the `Sink` parameter and is equivalent to:

```scala
source
  .via(flow1)
  .toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
  .run()
  .onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

Comment: So I guess my flow was working as intended but I was debugging it incorrectly with the use of the sink.